# JavaScript regular expression ( alphanumeric characters with _-)

Tags: javascript, regex, alphanumeric

I am having trouble forming regular expression containing all alphanumeric characters and one or two specific characters, such us `_` or `-`.

This expression works for all alphanumeric characters `/^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/`.

Comment: You need a regex to find another regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+$/
```

If you enter the dash sign "-" at a position where it can be interpreted as a range such as _- it would mean any characters matching _ or above in the ascii table.

Comment: Maybe I am looking for wrong expression :S I need to check if string only contains `/^[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+$/` and nothing else.

Comment: The expression /^[0-9a-zA-Z-_]+$/ will do just that, except that it will require at least one character to be entered. If empty strings are also accepted, the plus-sign "+" should be an asterisk "*"

Answer (score 2):

Add the special characters inside the square brackets

```
/^[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$/
```

To use this regex in javascript use this code (`yourPhrase` is the string you check vs the regexp)

```
var rexp = /^[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$/
if(rexp.test(yourPhrase)){
    //code to handle the test
}
```